# Ignore case using boost::regex_search

Tags: c++, boost-regex, ignore-case

How do you use `boost::regex_search` with the ignore case flags or constants in C++?

Please post an easy example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need something like this

```
boost::regex regex("your expression here", boost::regex::icase);
boost::smatch what;

string mystring;
bool search_result = boost::regex_search(mystring.begin(),mystring.end(), what, regex);
```

Comment: You can omit the "what" parameter (match results) if you don't need it, and you can pass the string itself instead of its iterators.

Answer (score 3):

Or something like this (without setting `boost::regex::icase`):

```
boost::regex regex("(?i)expression");
boost::smatch what;

string mystring;
bool search_result = boost::regex_search(mystring.begin(),mystring.end(), what, regex);
```